# 2D Gaussian distribution of squares coordinates

Tags: graphics, probability-or-statistics

I would like to imitate the structure of this great painting from Ellsworth Kelly in Mathematica. Yet with all the colored squares in Black and the beige one in white.

[image]

Below is what I have wrote to generate a square made out of 100 squares but I am confused about the next step :

How could I "Gaussianly sample" from the center 
How could I then assign different colors to the ones selected ?

```
Graphics@Flatten[
                 Table[Rectangle @@@ 
                       Table[{{i, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}}, 
                             {i, Range[0, 10, 1]}], 
                  {j,Range[0, 10, 1]}], 1]
```

Comment: some of us are uncultured and are not familiar with Kelly Elsworth, so perhaps you could explain better what you want. Also, "how could I gaussianly sample" is unclear; what should be sampled? positions? and what should be gaussian?

Comment: @acl, sorry for the confusion. It seems you and other got it perfectly though :-)

Comment: ok :) you should fix the question anyway, in case it useful to others in the future.

Comment: @acl,Truth to be told, I added a lot to show I try, but I would have happily ask how to reproduce this image sampling from a list of colors. What do you think?

Comment: A useful thing to add would be a description or link to the methods Ellsworth used to create the image. I've read that these are colored papers that were randomly numbered and placed in predetermined locations.  Likely there is some source that explains how the bivariate normal was used to achieve this.

Comment: It's Ellsworth Kelly, not Kelly Ellsworth.

Comment: You can extract the colour palette like this: `image = Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/wgMtl.png"]; ColorSetter@RGBColor[#] & /@ 
 Union@Round[Join @@ ImageData[image], 0.1]`, then use it in one of the solutions below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This reproduces the image decently. It works by sampling without replacement from all the positions, and randomly coloring them with a built-in color scheme.

```
size = 41; 
amountCovered = 0.40;
noSquares = Floor[amountCovered*size^2];
tiles = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, size}, {j, size}], 1];
probabilities = Flatten@GaussianMatrix[Floor[size/2]];
sample = RandomSample[probabilities -> tiles, noSquares];
colors = RandomInteger[21, noSquares];
mat = SparseArray[sample -> colors, {size, size}];
ArrayPlot[mat, Frame -> None, 
          ColorRules -> {0 -> RGBColor[{237, 233, 214}/255], 
                         x_ -> ColorData[54][x]}]
```

[image: nice colorful squares]]

For black and white, just replace colors with 1, and remove the `ColorRules` rules:

```
mat = SparseArray[sample -> 1, {size, size}];
ArrayPlot[mat, Frame -> None]
```

[image: black and white squares, sampled with gaussian probability]

**Choice of colors**

Choosing randomly from a set of colors instead of the built in `ColorData`:

```
lesCouleurs = {RGBColor[0.4, 0.4, 1], RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0.5], RGBColor[0, 0, 0]}
colors = RandomInteger[Length@lesCouleurs, noSquares];
mat = SparseArray[sample -> colors, {size, size}];
ArrayPlot[mat, Frame -> None, 
          ColorRules -> {0 -> RGBColor[{237, 233, 214}/255], 
                          x_ :>  lesCouleurs[[x]]}]
```

N.B. I was lazy in using `GaussianMatrix` for computing the probabilities, so only odd sizes work as expected.

Comment: Nice, +1! I didn't even know about `GaussianMatrix`.

Comment: @Verbeia Thanks! It seems it's intended use is as a kernel for image filtering, I found it while spelunking through the documentation a while back. It also does derivatives of the Gaussian function, and for any dimension. Quite nifty IMHO.

Comment: @Lars, How could I adjust you code such that the color is a random draw within that list for example : lesCouleurs={RGBColor[0.4,0.4,1],RGBColor[1,0.5,0.5],RGBColor[0,0,0]}
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 14):

One way to create an image similar to the one you have is with `ArrayPlot`.  The trick to "gaussianly sample" is to simply sample from a bivariate normal distribution and rescale the coordinates so they can be used for array rules in a `SparseArray`.

Here I use `Tally` to effectively bin the data on the grid.

Note that the color function can be changed to produce whatever colors you want.

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[0], 1000];

res = 50;

ArrayPlot[
 SparseArray[(#[[1]] -> #[[2]]) & /@ 
   Tally[Round[Rescale[data, {Min[data], Max[data]}, {1, res}]]]],
  ColorFunction -> (If[# == 0, White, ColorData["SunsetColors"][#]] &)]
```

[image]

It is quite simple to change to black and white by changing the `ColorFunction` to

```
ColorFunction -> (If[# == 0, White, Black]&)
```

Also, in the spirit of Ruebenko's solution, we can get nice random RGB colors using..

```
ColorFunction -> (If[# == 0, White, RGBColor[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 3]]] &)
```

Comment: Nice! Is there an advantage of `Tally` over `HistogramList`?

Comment: @Verbeia I think it is a matter of taste.  It can be useful to keep track of the cell counts rather than converting to {0,1} if one wants to create color images using say Image and subsequently do image processing. This can be accomplished with either route though.

Answer (score 10):

Here is something to get you started.

```
data = RandomVariate[
d = MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{2, 0}, {0, 2}}], 1000];
hl = HistogramList[data, {0.15}];

ArrayPlot[Sign[hl[[2]]]]
```

[image]

The trick is to get the right number of bins as the second argument of `HistogramList` and to have just the right number of points in `data`. Too many, and the whole area is occupied; too few and there aren't enough points.

Once you have the coordinates in `hl[[2]]`,  assigning a random color should be straightforward. I have left this as an exercise.

Comment: Edited to use *uncorrelated* bivariate normal noise.

Answer (score 10):

Here is my entry - thanks to Andy for centering...

```
n = 25;
data = Cases[
   IntegerPart[
    RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
      2000]*13], {_?(-n <= # <= n &), _?(-n <= # <= n &)}];
Graphics[{
  {White, Line[{{-n, -n}, {n, -n}, {n, n}, {-n, n}, {-n, -n}}]},
  {RGBColor @@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3}], Rectangle[#, # + 1]} & /@ 
   data}]
```

[image]

Have fun playing with the parameters....

Comment: I particularly like the use of random RGB colors.

Comment: @AndyRoss, hey thanks - you know what I have not done statistics for such a long time I can't get that thing in the center.... haha. It's good that you look over that stuff...

Comment: Change the mean of the MultinormalDistribution from {1,2} to {0,0}. That will center if for you.

Comment: Ah... right... Thanks. I need to go to bed....

Comment: @ruebenko, Thank you very much !

Answer (score 9):

You were talking about a square with 100 smaller squares, so you must be thinking of a 10x10 grid.

```
mat = ConstantArray[0, {10, 10}];
```

Here a bi-bormal distribution which is truncated at the boundaries of the square:

```
d = TruncatedDistribution[{{1, 10}, {1, 10}}, 
         BinormalDistribution[{5.5, 5.5}, {2, 2}, 0]
    ];
```

Drawing a few samples from this distribution, rounding the position value and increasing the matrix count:

```
Scan[(mat[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]]++) &, Round[RandomVariate[d, 100]]]
```

Plotting and coloring:

```
MatrixPlot[mat, ColorRules -> {0 -> Black, 1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green, 
                               4 -> Blue}, 
                ColorFunction -> (White &),
                Frame -> None
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just remove the colors in the ColorRules list you don't want. The default color is the one given by ColorFunction.

```
MatrixPlot[mat, ColorRules -> {0 -> Black}, 
                ColorFunction -> (White &), Frame -> None
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure I am answering the right question, but how about

```
With[{nonzero = 500, side = 100},
  SparseArray[
   Thread[
    Clip[#, {0, side}] &@
      Ceiling@RandomVariate[
        NormalDistribution[side/2, Sqrt[side]], {nonzero, 2}] -> 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, nonzero]
    ],
   {side, side}
   ]
  ] // ArrayPlot[#, ColorFunction \[Rule] "BlueGreenYellow", 
   ColorFunctionScaling \[Rule] True] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

EDIT: OK here's how this works. I will describe it from inside going out. `side` is the size of the array, `nonzero` the number of nonzero elements that we wish.

We start with `Ceiling@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[side/2, Sqrt[side]], {nonzero, 2}]` produces a set of random number pairs drawn from a Gaussian distribution, then makes them integer with `Ceiling` (introducing a slight bias but it shouldn't matter). `Clip` is then applied to this to force the resulting numbers to lie in the correct range for indices. The result is `nonzero` pairs of random numbers, all between `0` and `side`. `Rule` is then `Thread`ed around this and `RandomReal[{0, 1}, nonzero]`, and `SparseArray` wrapped around the whole thing, so that we end up using the pairs of Gaussian distributed random numbers as indices and fill in those positions with a `RandomReal`. If we then display the result with (eg) `ArrayPlot`, it looks like the plot above (the random entries in the matrix become random colours).

Comment: Great explanation! I wish there was such a description for every piece of code... Like an "explain" button" ... :)

Comment: @cormullion thanks! I thought I'd add it so that maybe someone would find this useful